# Transition from AsyncTask to Coroutines in Retrofit: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I keep getting error `IllegalArgumentException` when making minimal changes to transition from `AsyncTask` (before) to `Kotlin Coroutines` (after). Note that code is working as expected with `AsyncTask`.

Note: Retrofit is calling my own `.php` script that returns some object `SimpleResultObject` encoded in `json` String.

**Before the change:**

Retrofit:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("activity_signup.php")
fun activitySignUp(
        @Field("activity_id") activityId: Int,
        @Field("user_id") userId: Int) : Call<SimpleResultObject>
```

Activity (inside of AsyncTask):

```
@Override
protected doInBackground(...) {

        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LOCALHOST_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build()

            val service = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI::class.java)
            val call = service.activitySignUp(activity_id, userId)
            call.enqueue(Callback<SimpleResultObject>() {}
```

Receive object in `@onResponse` method and normally proceed futher.

**After the change:**

Retrofit:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("activity_signup.php")
 suspend fun activitySignUp(
            @Field("activity_id") activityId: Int,
            @Field("user_id") userId: Int): SimpleResultObject
```

Activity:

```
 fun signUp() {
        myActivityScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LOCALHOST_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build()

            val service = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI::class.java)
            try {
                val result = service.activitySignUp(specificResultObject.activityId, userId)
                } catch (t:Throwable)
```

Throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3) for method RetrofitAPI.activitySignUp`on `service.activitySignUp` line call

Note: `myActivityScope` is costum `CoroutineScope` that finished when hosting Activity finishes.

I have tried everything I could remember: adding `OkHttpClient`, changing to `MoshiConverterFactory`, trying other CoroutineScopes and Dispatchers, ...

EDIT: the problem might be on my `.php` side due to `Exeption` being above my argument number (maybe null result?), but don't know why something that worked before wouldn't work now.

Comment: Is that crash coming from the `retrofit.create()` call? If so, try moving your `gson`, `retrofit`, and `service` declaration/initialization outside of the coroutine. None of that varies at runtime and none of it requires a `Context` or anything strange, so you could have those as properties on whatever class contains `signUp()`. Also, what version of Retrofit are you using?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your help!. Sorry if it was not clear enough: the error is coming from the 'service.activitySignUp' call. And I am using Retrofit version 2.5.0. I expect that error must come from .php side but don't know why it would not work now when before it worked just fine.

Comment: You might still try moving the `gson`, `retrofit`, and `service` declaration/initialization outside of the coroutine, in case that helps. The error does not make a lot of sense, as you only have two parameters to `activitySignUp()`, so I do not know what "parameter #3" would mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have moved everything outside of coroutine but the issue persists. Thank you for your help anyway - hopefully there will be someone who would know how to solve this!

Comment: Does the code work correctly before migrating to the coroutines?

Comment: @aminography yes, it does. I made this even clearer now in the edits.

Comment: @Androidz I think it's due to library version, because Retrofit 2.5.0 does not support suspend function, which you are using that way, update to 2.6.0 should solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't crash for me when I use `"posts"` instead of `"activity_signup.php"` and `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"` instead of `LOCALHOST_URL` and changed the call to `service.activitySignUp(42, 35)` and with an empty.`SimpleResultObject` class. Does it crash for you with these changes? Since the error message is about parameter #3 and since you only have 2 parameters, I suspect your code in your question is not actually the code that was used when the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on responses to the question I made a few modifications to the code and managed to fix the issue. The most important, as @Mohammad Sianaki pointed out, was **rising Retrofit version from 25.0.0 to 26.0.0 that solved the problem**.

So for everyone else that might get the `IllegalArgumentException` for the argument above the parameter number - **consider checking Retrofit versions**.

Special thanks to everyone that helped, especially to @CommonsWare!

Answer (score 0):

The provided code in question has some structural issues.

First of all, it seems that a retrofit object is being created for each API call. So, it should be one for all API calls of the application.

Second, network operations should be executed in non-main threads. In the case of coroutines, they should be called in non-main contexts, like `Dispatchers.IO`.

Third, I think you should return a `Response<SimpleResultObject>` instead of `SimpleResultObject` in API functions.

Supposing above, I wrote some codes hoping to solve the problem. Because I think there are some hidden factors in question information.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.14.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'
}
```

**RetrofitAPI.kt**

```
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.Field
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface RetrofitAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("activity_signup.php")
    suspend fun activitySignUp(
        @Field("activity_id") activityId: Int,
        @Field("user_id") userId: Int
    ): Response<SimpleResultObject>

    // Other api declarations ...

}
```

**BaseApiManager.kt**

```
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.net.CookieManager
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

abstract class BaseApiManager(endPoint: String) {

    protected val retrofitAPI: RetrofitAPI =
        createAdapter(endPoint)
            .create(RetrofitAPI::class.java)

    private fun createAdapter(choice: String): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(choice)
            .client(createHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }

    companion object {

        private fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
            val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            val cookieHandler = CookieManager()
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor)

            httpClient.cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

            return httpClient.build()
        }
    }

}
```

**ApiManager.kt**

```
private const val API_END_POINT = "https://your.webservice.endpoint/"

object ApiManager : BaseApiManager(API_END_POINT) {

    suspend fun activitySignUp(
        activityId: Int,
        userId: Int
    ) = retrofitAPI.activitySignUp(activityId, userId)

    // Other api implementations ...

}
```

### Usage:

```
fun signUp() {
    myActivityScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ApiManager.activitySignUp(activityId, userId).also { response ->
            when {
                response.isSuccessful -> {
                    val result = response.body()
                    result?.apply {

                        // do something with the result
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    val code = response.code()
                    val message = response.message()

                    // do something with the error parameters...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will address all the points you mentioned. Firstly, I am creating single service object but I just included it like this for simplicty. Secondly, "suspended" functions on Retrofit are automatically called on back T so this is not an issue. Thirdly, "response" in result is not needed.